# Dict Class empty result

Tags: python

My datasource provides dicts, I would like to enricht the dicts and use them for something else.
But I can't get my head around the class to make a new dict, whatever I do, it always returns an empty dict.

```
class car(dict):
    def __init__(self, carId, data):
        self.carId = carId
        self.brand = data['Brand']
        self.type = data['Type']

    def addColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

car1 = {'Brand': 'Volkswagen', 'Type': 'Polo'}
car2 = {'Brand': 'Volvo', 'Type': 'C30'}

car1b = car("someID", car1)

print car1b['someID']
```

Comment: Try to modify the `__getitem__` method to access `data`.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen here? Why not `print car1b.brand`, which will give you `Volkswagen`?

Comment: I was expecting the same result with car1b['brand'] as with car1b.brand

Comment: your class does not create dicts and that's why `car1b['brand']` **does not work**. It creates instances of itself and that's why `car1b.brand` **does work**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `self.carId = carId` to `self[carId] = carId` .

Try this

```
class car(dict):
    def __init__(self, carId, data):
        self[carId] = carId
        self.brand = data['Brand']
        self.type = data['Type']

    def addColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

car1 = {'Brand': 'Volkswagen', 'Type': 'Polo'}
car2 = {'Brand': 'Volvo', 'Type': 'C30'}

car1b = car("someID", car1)

print( car1b["someID"])
```

Comment: thanks. by screwing up . and [..] I was making instances and not values of an instance as Ev. Kounis pointed out..